# How to sort model by sum of attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-order-by

I have an Artist model represented by serializer

```
class ArtistSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :name,
             :followers_total_count

  def followers_total_count
    [
      object.facebook_like_count,
      object.soundcloud_like_count,
      object.instagram_like_count,
      object.twitter_like_count,
      object.mixcloud_like_count,
      object.youtube_like_count
    ].map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
  end
end
```

How to sort `Artist.all` by sum of all providers like count.

Example:

Artist1

- facebook_like_count => 100
- twitter_like_count => 50

Artist2

- instagram_like_count => 20
- twitter_like_count => 1000

order should be [Artist2, Artist1]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `:followers_total_count` is an integer, you could try this

```
Artist.order(:followers_total_count, :desc)
```